# ReactJS/Nivo Graphs - How to modify the x-axis to be ascending date order when data contains "incomplete" data?

Tags: reactjs, charts

**Question:** How can I "reformat" the x-axis to be in ascending date, when the data contains a variable amount of dates within it?

I have some data that contains variable amounts of "date" associated with it. For example, Line One contains:

```
{ x: "2019-05-01", y: 2 },
{ x: "2019-06-01", y: 7 },
{ x: "2020-03-01", y: 1 }
```

Whereas Line Two contains:

```
{ x: "2019-05-01", y: 1 },
{ x: "2019-06-01", y: 5 },
{ x: "2020-05-01", y: 5 }
```

Code box: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-almeida-x7rnd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The data is "uneven" on the x-axis, hence why it looks weird. I realise that if I were to put in "dummy dates" and data to it, then I can dictate the x-axis to become the format I want, the issue is dummy dates + data, because then it doesn't accurately model my database, so I want to avoid something like this.

What I've done so far is look over the documentation, I've tried adding in the `type: "time"` format to `xscale`, but I'm getting error

> `v.getTime()` is not a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add `format` to both `ResponsiveLine` Component and `xScale` property in order to use a time scale

> **xFormat**:
>
> Optional formatter for x values.
>
> The formatted value can then be used for labels & tooltips.
>
> **If you use a time scale, you must provide a time format as values are converted to Date objects**.

Complete config: ([Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-glitter-txvx8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark))

```
import React from "react";
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 350 }} className="App">
      <ResponsiveLine
        data={[
          {
            id: "LineOne",
            data: [
              { x: "2019-05-01", y: 2 },
              { x: "2019-06-01", y: 7 },
              { x: "2020-03-01", y: 1 }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "LineTwo",
            data: [
              { x: "2019-05-01", y: 1 },
              { x: "2019-06-01", y: 5 },
              { x: "2020-05-01", y: 5 }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "LineThree",
            data: [
              { x: "2020-02-01", y: 4 },
              { x: "2020-03-01", y: 6 },
              { x: "2020-04-01", y: 1 }
            ]
          }
        ]}
        margin={{ top: 50, right: 110, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
        xScale={{
          type: "time",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }}
        xFormat="time:%Y-%m-%d"
        yScale={{
          type: "linear",
          min: "auto",
          max: "auto",
          stacked: false,
          reverse: false
        }}
        axisTop={null}
        axisRight={null}
        axisLeft={{
          orient: "left",
          tickSize: 5,
          tickPadding: 5,
          tickRotation: 0,
          legend: "count",
          legendOffset: -40,
          legendPosition: "middle"
        }}
        axisBottom={{
          format: "%b %d",
          //tickValues: "every 2 days",
          // tickRotation: -90,
          legend: "time scale",
          legendOffset: -12
        }}
        colors={{ scheme: "nivo" }}
        pointSize={10}
        pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
        pointBorderWidth={2}
        pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
        pointLabel="y"
        pointLabelYOffset={-12}
        useMesh={true}
        legends={[
          {
            anchor: "bottom-right",
            direction: "column",
            justify: false,
            translateX: 100,
            translateY: 0,
            itemsSpacing: 0,
            itemDirection: "left-to-right",
            itemWidth: 80,
            itemHeight: 20,
            itemOpacity: 0.75,
            symbolSize: 12,
            symbolShape: "circle",
            symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
            effects: [
              {
                on: "hover",
                style: {
                  itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
                  itemOpacity: 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]}
      />
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit youthful-glitter-txvx8]

Comment: Great example, thanks! I have a question. How you fix the date displayed at minus - 1 day ? In you example, Line One and Two start 2019-04-30 instead of 2019-05-01?

Answer (score 1):

modified the following things and tested with random (none sorted data)

- xscale type to time with the format
- add indexBy="date" property to responsiveline element
- add format: "%Y-%m-%d" to your axis bottom,

  you can find a working example here

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mestorf-zeozb

```
export default function App()
 { return (
 <div style={{ height: 350 }} className="App">

          <ResponsiveLine
    
                data={[
                  {
                    id: "LineOne",
                    data: [
                      { x: "2019-05-01", y: 2 },
                      { x: "2019-06-01", y: 7 },
                      { x: "2020-03-01", y: 1 },
                      { x: "2017-09-01", y: 6 }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    id: "LineTwo",
                    data: [
                      { x: "2019-05-01", y: 1 },
                      { x: "2019-06-01", y: 5 },
                      { x: "2020-05-01", y: 5 },
                      { x: "2018-09-01", y: 3 }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    id: "LineThree",
                    data: [
                      { x: "2020-02-01", y: 4 },
                      { x: "2020-03-01", y: 6 },
                      { x: "2020-04-01", y: 1 }
                    ]
                  }
                ]}
                indexBy="date"
                margin={{ top: 50, right: 110, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
                xScale={{
                  type: "time",
                  format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                  precision: "day"
                }}
                yScale={{ type: "linear", stacked: false, min: 0, max: "auto" }}
                axisTop={null}
                axisRight={null}
                axisBottom={{
                  orient: "bottom",
                  tickSize: 5,
                  format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                  tickPadding: 5,
                  tickRotation: -65,
                  legend: "time",
                  legendOffset: 40,
                  legendPosition: "middle"
                }}
                axisLeft={{
                  orient: "left",
                  tickSize: 5,
                  tickPadding: 5,
                  tickRotation: 0,
                  legend: "count",
                  legendOffset: -40,
                  legendPosition: "middle"
                }}
                colors={{ scheme: "nivo" }}
                pointSize={10}
                pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
                pointBorderWidth={2}
                pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
                pointLabel="y"
                pointLabelYOffset={-12}
                useMesh={true}
                legends={[
                  {
                    anchor: "bottom-right",
                    direction: "column",
                    justify: false,
                    translateX: 100,
                    translateY: 0,
                    itemsSpacing: 0,
                    itemDirection: "left-to-right",
                    itemWidth: 80,
                    itemHeight: 20,
                    itemOpacity: 0.75,
                    symbolSize: 12,
                    symbolShape: "circle",
                    symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
                    effects: [
                      {
                        on: "hover",
                        style: {
                          itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
                          itemOpacity: 1
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]}
              />
              )
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note is that in the above answers, the date on the actual chart is -1 from the date in the data. To solve this, add "useUTC: false" to your xScale props.